# Magento configurable product "Requested Quantity not available" Redirects to simple product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When I'm on a configurable product in Magento and I add a quantity that isn't available, Magento then redirects me to the simple product, which is not visible individually. Thus it throws me a 404 Error.

For example, if I'm on `/all-white-paint` which has many simple products based on paint pot size, I order 5 of a product with only 4 in stock, rather than staying on this page Magento takes me to `/all-white-750ml`

How can I prevent this from happening, and avoid the 404 - Without enabling the product to be visible?

Comment: Are you using the Simple Configurable Products extension (or something similar)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the SCP extension